# matching strings with comma

Tags: r, regex

The question might be very easy but I am new to `R`, I am trying to extract from a column some strings matching with this string "Primary, pupils". So I tried this

```
grepl("(.*?)primary,[:space:] pupils(.*?)", df$some_column,ignore.case=TRUE)
```

and

```
grepl("(.*?)primary,[:space:](.*?)", df$some_column,ignore.case=TRUE)
```

but none of them seems to work. Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Don't "speak" `r`, but you have `[:space:]` **as well** as an actual space in the first expression. Is that intended?

Comment: Note that `.*?` are redundant in `grep`/`grepl` because these functions allow a *partial* match (=no full string match is required).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
grepl("primary,[[:space:]]*pupils", df$some_column,ignore.case=TRUE)
```

The pattern will match:

- `primary,` - a liteal substring (case insensitive mode is ON due to `ignore.case=TRUE` argument)
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `pupils` - a literal `pupils` substring (case insensitive)

**NOTE**: `[:space:]` POSIX character class should be included into a bracket expression, otherwise, it matches a single char that is defined inside `[...]`, that is, `[:space:]` will match a single char: `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c` or `e`.

See a [small demo](https://ideone.com/EQIGue):

```
x <- c("1 primary, pupils", "2 PRIMARY,pupils tex", "no value")
grepl("primary,[[:space:]]*pupils", x,ignore.case=TRUE)
## => [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
grep("primary,[[:space:]]*pupils", x,ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)
## => [1] "1 primary, pupils"    "2 PRIMARY,pupils tex"
```